# How to add rows to CollectionType in Symfony2 Form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, formcollection

I'm trying to create a "complex form" using Symfony2. One field of this form is created from another "simple form", and, 6 fields of the form are created from another "simple form" (so it's a repeated field, yes). It's like a "Form of forms" or embedded form.

The following code correspond to the first "simple form" that is only one field of the "complex form":

```
<?php

namespace SisEvo\ConfiguracionBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class VariableReguladaElectricoValoresDatosType extends AbstractType{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('valor');          
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' =>     'SisEvo\ConfiguracionBundle\Entity\VariableReguladaElectricoValoresDatos'
        ));
    }

}
```

The other "simple form" that will be repeated 6 times in the "complex form":

```
<?php

namespace SisEvo\MaestroBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;


class VariablesMedidaType extends AbstractType{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array     $options) {
         $builder->add("medida", EntityType::class, array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'class' => 'MaestroBundle:VariablesMedida',
                    'choice_label' => 'medida',
                ));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
     public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'SisEvo\MaestroBundle\Entity\VariablesMedida'
         ));
    }

}
```

And finally, the "complex form":

```
<?php

namespace SisEvo\ConfiguracionBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use SisEvo\MaestroBundle\Form\VariablesMedidaType;
use SisEvo\ConfiguracionBundle\Form\VariableReguladaElectricoValoresDatosType;

class VariableReguladaElectricoValoresType extends AbstractType {

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('idDatos', CollectionType::class, array(
                // each entry in the array will be an "email" field
                'entry_type' => VariableReguladaElectricoValoresDatosType::class,
                // these options are passed to each "email" type
                'entry_options' => array(
                    'attr' => array(
                        'rows' => 6
                    //,'class' => 'VariableReguladaElectricoValoresDatos'
                    )),
            ))
            //->add('valores', 'collection', array('type' => new VariableReguladaElectricoValoresDatosType()))
            ->add('idMedida', new VariablesMedidaType());
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'SisEvo\ConfiguracionBundle\Entity\VariableReguladaElectricoValores'
        , 'cascade_validation' => true
    ));
    }

}
```

`idMedida` field is working fine, but I need some help to print `idDatos` field, that should be printed 6 times. I tried to do it with the option rows as you can see in the code, but is not working.

In the twig file I'm trying to print the form using `{{ form_widget(myComplexForm) }}`

Any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

When you create your form in Controller, you can create there 6 entities of `SisEvo\ConfiguracionBundle\Entity\VariableReguladaElectricoValoresDatos` as an `ArrayCollection` and set it as idDatos, then pass it to form as `setData`  method of a form